# Is it possible to automatically create ViewSets and Serializers for each Model?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In our project we have a huge amount of models and some of them are still in the works. I would like to create our REST API using the Django Rest Framework but don't want to create a separate serializer class and ModelViewSet for each Model we have (as most of them should be accessible via API).

Currently there is a Serializer like this for each of our models:

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = '__all__'
```

Additionally in views.py there is the ModelViewSet:

```
class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

Is it possible to somehow reduce the amount of code and make this approach a bit more flexible? I am thinking of something like this:

```
for model in models:
    ser = createSerializer()
    createViewSet(ser)
```

Where with each call a separate class is created. Or is there even a class which makes this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based of @bdoubleus answer, we can use the viewset with a small modification:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

# Template class for serializing
class GeneralSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'

class GenericAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
        self.queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        serializer = GeneralSerializer
        serializer.Meta.model = self.model
        self.serializer_class = serializer
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

To conclude this generator we need to create an URL route for each model in `urls.py`:

```
app = apps.get_app_config('testapp')

for model_name, model in app.models.items():
    urlpatterns.append(path(model_name, views.GenericAPIView.as_view(), {'model': model}))
```

Comment: I recently went down the rabbit hole of wondering how far you can go with this concept an happened to find this answer and wanted to contribute [this presentation](https://youtu.be/fNXpQ14LKfk) that Mjumbe Poe did at DjangoCon2018. It is both relevant to this question and really helped me a understand how dynamic you can be with class creation in Django.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a generalized class for your view then pass the model and any other info through [extra url paramaters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions).

For example:

```
class URLModelAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.model = kwargs.pop('model')
        self.queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        self.serializer = kwargs.pop('serializer')
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import models, serializers, views

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        'customer/',
        views.URLModelAPIView.as_view(),
        {
            'model': models.Customer,
            'serializer': serializers.CustomerSerializer,
        }
    ),
    path(
        'customer_contact/',
        views.URLModelAPIView.as_view(),
        {
            'model': models.CustomerContact,
            'serializer': serializers.CustomerContactSerializer,
        }
    ),
]
```

The same logic applies for viewsets when using a router.

Comment: That is pretty interesting, I will try this!

Comment: I tried it now and -sadly enough- I am getting an error: `AttributeError: type object 'URLModelAPIView' has no attribute 'as_view'`.

Comment: Ah, it's supposed to be `generics.ListAPIView`, I've update the answer.

Comment: This still throws errors for the query set and the serializer class, where the query set is pretty easy, but the serializer class could be more difficult.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I use similar logic but with just the serializer - didn't have time to check what would happen with models when accessing the URL. You can get the serializer in the same way as the model through URL keyword arguments in `urlpatterns`. I've updated the answer to account for the queryset too.